# preg_replace - array of individual replacements

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to achieve the following:

`$subject = 'a b a';

$search = 'a';

$replace = '1';`

Desired result:

`Array

(

[0] => 1 b a

    [1] => a b 1

)`

Is there any way of achieving this with preg_replace?

`preg_replace('/\b'.$search.'(?=\s+|$)/u', $replace, array($subject));`

will return all the replacments in the same result:

`Array

(

    [0] => 1 b 1

)`

Cheers

Comment: I think I'm losing it ;) Why exactly do you pass `$subject` as an array?

Comment: preg_replace can return a string or an array depending on the type of $subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible. You can specify a limit of replacements in the optional fourth parameter, but that always starts at the beginning.

It could be possible to achieve what you're looking for with [`preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). You would just have to split your string on all occasions of your search pattern and then mess with them one by one. If your search pattern is just a simple string, you can achieve the same with `explode()`. If you need help figuring this approach out, I'll be happy to help.

**EDIT**: Let's see if this works for you:

```
$subject = 'a b a';
$pattern = '/a/';
$replace = 1;

// We split the string up on all of its matches and obtain the matches, too
$parts = preg_split($pattern, $subject);
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

$numParts = count($parts);
$results = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < $numParts; $i++)
{
    // We're modifying a copy of the parts every time
    $partsCopy = $parts;

    // First, replace one of the matches
    $partsCopy[$i] = $replace.$partsCopy[$i];

    // Prepend the matching string to those parts that are not supposed to be replaced yet
    foreach ($partsCopy as $index => &$value)
    {
        if ($index != $i && $index != 0)
            $value = $matches[0][$index - 1].$value;
    }

    // Bring it all back together now
    $results[] = implode('', $partsCopy);
}

print_r($results);
```

Note: This is not tested yet. Please report whether it works.

**EDIT 2**:

I tested it with your example now, fixed a few things and it works now (at least with that example).

Answer (score 1):

```
function multipleReplace($search,$subject,$replace) {
    preg_match_all($search, $subject,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    foreach($matches as $match) {
    if (is_array($match)) {
        foreach ($match as $submatch) {
        list($string,$start) = $submatch;
        $length = strlen($string);
        $val = "";
        if ($start - 1 > 0) {
            $val .= substr($subject,0,$start);
        }
        $val .= preg_replace($search,$string,$replace);
        $val .= substr($subject,$start + $length);
        $ret[] = $val;
        }
    }
    }
    return $ret;
}

$search = 'a';

print_r(multipleReplace('/\b'.$search.'(?=\s+|$)/u','a b a','1'));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 b a
    [1] => a b 1
)
```

Comment: This would not always work as replacing in substrings is not equal to replacing in the full string. But that could of course be worked around. This is just a hint as to what you will have to do to get it working.